# How to connect Postgres SQL amazon RDS instance from pgadmin fromthe local machine?It giving me the following error

Tags: rds

[image]

How to connect Postgres SQL amazon RDS instance from pgAdmin4 from the local machine?It giving me the following error.

Answer (score -1):

Here are the things you need to check.

The communication is out of VPC. So your RDS must accessible via public.

1. Check Publically access - YES.
2. The subnets which all are in the Subnet group should be public subnets.
3. In RDS security group allow your IP address.
4. Check the ACL as well.